# Left join combined with full outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, full-outer-join

There is a main table, which has references to two other tables. These two tables might have multiple entries per reference.

Main:

```
| id | mname | sid | lid |
|----|-------|-----|-----|
|  1 | a1    |   1 |   2 |
|  2 | a2    |   2 |   3 |
|  3 | a3    |   1 |   1 |
```

Short:

```
| id | lang | sdesc |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 | de   | S1    |
|  1 | en   | S2    |
|  2 | de   | S3    |
|  3 | en   | S4    |
```

`(id, lang)` is unique.

Long:

```
| id | lang | ldesc |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 | de   | L1    |
|  1 | en   | L2    |
|  2 | de   | L3    |
|  3 | en   | L4    |
```

`(id, lang)` is unique.

I want to join these three tables to have the following result:

```
| mname | lang | sdesc  | ldesc  |
|-------|------|--------|--------|
| a1    | de   | S1     | L3     |
| a1    | en   | S2     | (null) |
| a2    | de   | S3     | (null) |
| a2    | en   | (null) | L4     |
| a3    | de   | S1     | L1     |
| a3    | en   | S2     | L2     |
```

---

My first try was ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3cf7/5/0))

```
select m.mname, s.lang, s.sdesc, l.lang, l.ldesc
from main m
left join short_desc s on s.id = m.sid
left join long_desc l on l.id = m.lid
```

which gives way too many entries.

Next one was ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3cf7/6/0))

```
select m.mname, s.lang, s.sdesc, l.lang, l.ldesc
from main m
left join short_desc s on s.id = m.sid
left join long_desc l on l.id = m.lid
where s.lang = l.lang
```

which leaves out valid entries.

After many variations of the above and a lot of playing around, I came up with ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3cf7/8/0))

```
with x1 as (select m.id, m.mname, s.lang, s.sdesc
            from main m
            join short_desc s on s.id = m.sid),
     x2 as (select m.id, m.mname, l.lang, l.ldesc
            from main m
            join long_desc l on l.id = m.lid)
select coalesce(x1.mname, x2.mname) mname,
       coalesce(x1.lang, x2.lang) lang,
       x1.sdesc,
       x2.ldesc
from x1
full outer join x2 on x2.id = x1.id and x2.lang = x1.lang
```

which gives the desired result, but to me this seems excessive for such a simple (?) requirement.

So here's my question, is there a simpler approach?

Comment: `... from main m cross join (select * from unnest(array['de','en'])) lang(code) left join short_desc s on s.id = m.sid and lang.code = s.lang ...`

Comment: Your data and desired result don't match.  Your result asks for a row a2, en, null, L4, but your data has L4 against id 3.

Comment: @RelativePHPNewbie Yes, `m.lid = l.id`, i.e. `m = (2, a2, 2, *3*)` and `l = (*3*, en, L4)`

Comment: @Abelisto Wow, care to add this as an answer? I don't understand this yet, but it seems to work ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3cf7/61/0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO what you are missed in the your data schema is the dictionary of the available languages. If introduce it, all other becomes simpler.

The desired dictionary cold be:

- the simple constant like `array['en','de','fr']`
- the true table
- the view collecting language codes from tables like `short_desc`, `long_desc` etc

It is up to you which case is more appropriate for your purposes.

In the example below we consider the languages dictionary as CTE:

```
with lang(code) as (values('en'),('de'),('fr'))
select m.*, lang.code
from main m cross join lang;

╔════╤═══════╤═════╤═════╤══════╗
║ id │ mname │ sid │ lid │ code ║
╠════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪══════╣
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ en   ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ en   ║
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ en   ║
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ de   ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ de   ║
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ de   ║
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ fr   ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ fr   ║
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ fr   ║
╚════╧═══════╧═════╧═════╧══════╝
(9 rows)
```

As you can see, now we have the individual row for each language and the next and the last step is join other two tables to the query above using `id` and `lang` fields:

```
with lang(code) as (values('en'),('de'),('fr'))
select m.*, lang.code, s.sdesc, l.ldesc
from main m cross join lang
  left join short_desc s on s.id = m.sid and s.lang = lang.code
  left join long_desc l on l.id = m.lid and l.lang = lang.code;

╔════╤═══════╤═════╤═════╤══════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ id │ mname │ sid │ lid │ code │ sdesc │ ldesc ║
╠════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ de   │ S1    │ L1    ║
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ en   │ S2    │ L2    ║
║  3 │ a3    │   1 │   1 │ fr   │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░  ║
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ de   │ S1    │ L3    ║
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ en   │ S2    │ ░░░░  ║
║  1 │ a1    │   1 │   2 │ fr   │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░  ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ de   │ S3    │ ░░░░  ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ en   │ ░░░░  │ L4    ║
║  2 │ a2    │   2 │   3 │ fr   │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░  ║
╚════╧═══════╧═════╧═════╧══════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `left join` with the condition on `lang` *in* the `on` clause:

```
select m.mname, s.lang, s.sdesc, l.lang, l.ldesc
from main m left join
     short_desc s
     on s.id = m.sid left join
     long_desc l
     on l.id = m.lid and s.lang = l.lang;
```

This should be the Goldilock's solution, with just the right number of rows.

Or even:

```
select m.mname, s.lang, s.sdesc, l.lang, l.ldesc
from main m left join
     short_desc s
     on s.id = m.sid left join
     long_desc l
     on l.id = m.lid and (s.lang = l.lang or s.lang is null);
```

Comment: This works for entries, where `ldesc` is null, but it leaves out entries where `sdesc` is null, as in the "a2 (null) L4" row ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3cf7/9/0)).